# Spinnaker - SQL backend for front50

Tags: spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I am trying to setup SQL backend for front50 using the document below.

https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/productionize/persistence/front50-sql/

I have fron50-local.yaml for the mysql config.

But, not sure how to disable persistent storage in halyard config. Here, I can not completely remove persistentStorage and persistentStoreType should be one of a3,azs,gcs,redis,s3,oracle.
There is no option to disable persistent storage here.

```
persistentStorage:
    persistentStoreType: s3
    azs: {}        
    gcs:          
      rootFolder: front50
    redis: {}       
    s3:           
      bucket: spinnaker
      rootFolder: front50             
      maxKeys: 1000 
    oracle: {}
```

Answer (score 2):

So within your front50-local.yaml you will want to disable the service you used to utilize e.g.

```
spinnaker:
  gcs:
    enabled: false
  s3:
    enabled: false
```

You may need/want to remove the section from your halconfig and run your apply with

`hal deploy apply --no-validate`

There are a number of users dealing with these same issues and some more help might be found on the Slack: https://join.spinnaker.io/

Comment: This should be in the spinnaker documentation, this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed the same issue just recently. Maybe this is because, for example Kayenta (which is an optional component to enable) is still missing the non-object storage persistent support, or...

I've created a GitHub issue on this here: https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/5447